# UDF Vlookup Sum Error. Always returns "#VALUE!"

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a function where the function returns the Sum of all Return Values of Vlookup. The Lookup Value has Parameters separated by "&". Additionally, "DD","DD0" of "DD00" has to added before the parameter to match the lookup value in lookup range. For example, Cell(1,2)="DD003&03A", the function should sum the return value of DD003 and DD003A. The following is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function DPPR_Vlookup(Lookup_Value As String, Lookup_Range As Range, Column_Index As Long, Optional Match_Case As Integer) As Variant

Dim D_Code() As String

Dim Pos_1 As Long

Dim i As Integer

Dim Sum_Value As Long

Dim x1 As Long
Dim x2 As Long
Dim x3 As Long


Pos_1 = InStr(1, Lookup_Value, "&", vbTextCompare)

    With Application.WorksheetFunction

        If Pos_1 = 0 Then

        DPPR_Vlookup = .VLookup(Lookup_Value, Lookup_Range, Column_Index, Match_Case)

        Else

        D_Code() = Split(Lookup_Value, "&")

            Sum_Value = 0

            For i = 1 To UBound(D_Code())

                If IsError(.VLookup("DD" & D_Code(i), Lookup_Range, Column_Index, Match_Case)) = True Then

                x1 = 0

                Else

                x1 = .VLookup("DD" & D_Code(i), Lookup_Range, Column_Index, Match_Case)

                End If


                If IsError(.VLookup("DD0" & D_Code(i), Lookup_Range, Column_Index, Match_Case)) = True Then

                x2 = 0

                Else

                x2 = .VLookup("DD0" & D_Code(i), Lookup_Range, Column_Index, Match_Case)

                End If


                If IsError(.VLookup("DD00" & D_Code(i), Lookup_Range, Column_Index, Match_Case)) = True Then

                x3 = 0

                Else

                x3 = .VLookup("DD00" & D_Code(i), Lookup_Range, Column_Index, Match_Case)

                End If


                Sum_Value = Sum_Value + x1 + x2 + x3

                x1 = 0
                x2 = 0
                x3 = 0

            Next i


DPPR_Vlookup = Sum_Value


        End If

    End With

End Function
```

The result for all parameters with "&" is always "#VALUE!". I have taken errors into consideration and the value should have been 0. Additionally, the value is of both DD003 and DD003A are present in the lookup_range but the function returns only "#VALUE!". Please help.

Comment: A sample of your worksheet and expected results would help with understanding your query

Comment: Can you please give some example data and how you use the function in a formula? See [mcve]. To debug your function create a helper procedure to call your function. This way you will be able do go through it step by step using F8 and check where it goes wrong.

Comment: You haven't actually handled errors. `application.worksheetfunction.vlookup` raises a **run-time** error if the lookup value isn't found, which will cause a `#VALUE!` error. You need to use `application.vlookup` which returns an **error value** that you can inspect with `iserror`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for the first value of `DD003&03A` you don't need to add a prefix. Also the array index that the `Split` method returns starts with `0` therefore you need to start with `i = 0` or even better dynamically with `i = LBound(D_Code())`.

As mentioned in the comment `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup` returns a run-time error that cannot be caught with `IsError()` so I changed to `Application.Vlookup`.

I also added an array for possible prefixes so we can easily use a loop instead of repeating the same code over and over.

Finally use a test procedure to easily debug your function, so you can go through it step by step using F8.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test_DPPR_Vlookup()

    Debug.Print DPPR_Vlookup([E2], [A:B], 2, 0)

End Sub

Public Function DPPR_Vlookup(Lookup_Value As String, Lookup_Range As Variant, Column_Index As Variant, Optional Match_Case As Boolean) As Variant
    Dim Pos_1 As Long
    Pos_1 = InStr(1, Lookup_Value, "&", vbTextCompare)

    Dim Prefix As Variant
    Dim Prefixes() As Variant
    Prefixes = Array("", "DD", "DD0", "DD00") 'note that the first is needed to also lookup without prefixes (first item)

    With Application
        If Pos_1 = 0 Then
            DPPR_Vlookup = .VLookup(Lookup_Value, Lookup_Range, Column_Index, Match_Case)
        Else
            Dim D_Code() As String
            D_Code() = Split(Lookup_Value, "&")

            Dim Sum_Value As Long
            Sum_Value = 0

            Dim i As Long, LookupResult As Variant
            For i = 0 To UBound(D_Code()) 'note array item counting starts with 0
                For Each Prefix In Prefixes
                    LookupResult = .VLookup(Prefix & D_Code(i), Lookup_Range, Column_Index, Match_Case)
                    If Not IsError(LookupResult) Then
                        Sum_Value = Sum_Value + LookupResult
                    End If
                Next Prefix
            Next i

            DPPR_Vlookup = Sum_Value
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

The formula used for `Result` is `=DPPR_Vlookup(E2,A:B,2,0)`

[image]